# Google Cloud Platform push subscription sending duplicate message ID fields

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

We have a GCP pubsub topic with a push subscription pointing at a Cloud Run app. The push subscription is sending our Cloud Run endpoint the following json, with duplicate messageId/message_id fields:

```json
{
  "message": {
    "attributes": {
      "bucketId": "...",
      "eventTime": "2021-07-22T15:56:45.913174Z",
      "eventType": "OBJECT_FINALIZE",
      "notificationConfig": "...",
      "objectGeneration": "1626969405908262",
      "objectId": "...",
      "payloadFormat": "JSON_API_V1"
    },
    "data": "...",
    "messageId": "2717017549133308",
    "message_id": "2717017549133308",
    "publishTime": "2021-07-22T15:56:46.081Z",
    "publish_time": "2021-07-22T15:56:46.081Z"
  },
  "subscription": "projects/.../subscriptions/..."
}
```

The problem arises when we attempt to convert this json into a [ReceivedMessage](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto) protobuf object with:

```java
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ReceivedMessage;

ReceivedMessage.Builder receivedMessageBuilder = ReceivedMessage.newBuilder();
JsonFormat.parser().merge(json, receivedMessageBuilder);
```

I'm using the latest version of protobuf-java in my Cloud Run app:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.17.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Since the json is being generated by GCP, and we are converting the json to a protobuf object defined by Google, I expected it to work fine. But instead we receive the following error:

```
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Field google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.message_id has already been set.
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1648)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1500)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1458)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.parseFieldValue(JsonFormat.java:1999)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1663)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1500)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1458)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1340)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$Parser.merge(JsonFormat.java:476)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? If I manually remove the duplicated fields (both `messageId` and `publishTime`), the message gets converted just fine as expected. But since the json is being generated by GCP internally, I don't have any control over it in the cloud environment. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can successfully convert this json into a `com.google.pubsub.v1.ReceivedMessage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an unfortunate quirk of a change made to the way the fields are represented in the JSON. Originally, "message_id" and "publish_time" were used, but in order to match [Protocol Buffer JSON standards](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json), they were changed to "publishTime" and "messageId", respectively. In order to ensure backwards compatibility for those who depended on the old way, both are written to the message. Support for this case in the JSON parsers has changed over the years and there is an [open issue for protocol buffers](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5414) to deal with it. For now, the only option is to remove the fields from the received JSON before calling `JsonFormat.parser().merge`.

Comment: Okay, good info, thanks! 

I ended up providing my own POJO that mirrors the ReceivedMessage protobuf, using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` to deserialize the json, and pulling the payload off that way.